# Discrepancy with lsof command when trying to get the count of open files per process

Tags: lsof

I am trying to get a list of open files per process. I ran the following one-liner from [PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=350764):

```
lsof | perl -lane '$x{"$F[0]:$F[1]"}++;
END { print "$x{$_}\t$_" for sort {$x{$a}<=>$x{$b}} keys %x}'
```

It returns the total count of open files, and the process name and pid. The result is sorted in ascending order, and the last line is as follows:

```
1065702 java:15437
```

So when I run `lsof -p 15437`, I would expect it to return the same number, however I'm getting:

```
$ lsof -p 15437 | wc -l
403
```

Why the discrepancy?

**Addendum**

A third source of discrepancy:

```
$ cd /proc/15437/fd
$ ls -1 | wc -l
216
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`lsof` without arguments gives you the information for all the threads of the every process.

While `lsof -p "$pid"` only lists open files for the process.

To get the same number, you'd need:

```
lsof -a -K -p "$pid"
```

Also note that `lsof` doesn't only list files open on file descriptors, it also lists mmapped files (as seen in `/proc/*/task/*/maps`), the current working directory (as seen in `/proc/*/task/*/cwd`), the root directory (`/proc/*/task/*/root`).

Comment: @zevzek, threads / lwps / tasks depending on how they're called can have different fd / mappings, etc on some systems, even Linux.

Comment: @zevzek, it doesn't need to care. On Linux, it can get the info from /proc/pid/task/fd/*

Comment: @zevzek, probably not, [you couldn't even tell if two fds from the same process share the same open file description in Linux before 3.5](/q/191967). In any case, I agree that that command in itself is not particularly useful other than to show how to get the same numbers as when you use `lsof` without options like this question is asking. It's still useful to be able to tell what file a thread is using.