# Why do "lsof -u USER" and "lsof | grep USER" return different results?

Tags: tomcat, lsof

On my system:

```
root@NOTIFICATION:/# lsof | wc -l
24187
root@NOTIFICATION:/# lsof -u tomcat7 | wc -l
224
root@NOTIFICATION:/# lsof | grep tomcat7 | wc -l
20646
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Discrepancy with lsof command when trying to get the count of open files per process](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199479/discrepancy-with-lsof-command-when-trying-to-get-the-count-of-open-files-per-pro)

Answer (score 4):

You have two different selections:

- `lsof -u tomcat7` lists open files belonging to tomcat7, whatever their names.
- `lsof | grep tomcat7` lists open files with `tomcat7` in their name ( or as a string in the line, be it user or group) irrespective of their owners.